# How to call the quartiles?

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem how to call the quartiles. 
This is csv file: [drinksbycountry.csv](https://github.com/sashiupadhyayula/Datasets/blob/master/drinksbycountry.csv)
I make new column where I show the quantile of value from column: 'beer servings'.

```
df['nowa'] = pd.qcut(df['beer_servings'],6)
df.loc[1:5,['country', 'continent0','nowa' ]]
```

As the result:

[image]

I don't want to have intervals like: (225.0, 376.0].
I would like to show: 'group 1', 'group 2'
How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use parameter `labels`:

> **labels** : array or boolean, default None
>   Used as labels for the resulting bins. Must be of the same length as the resulting bins. If False, return only integer indicators of the bins.

```
df['nowa'] = 'group ' + pd.qcut(df['beer_servings'],6, labels=False).astype(str)
```

Also is possible create labels in list - e.g. in list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
labels = [f'group {x}' for x in range(6)]
df['nowa'] =  pd.qcut(df['beer_servings'],6, labels=labels)
```